# Sorting result of a select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have following select:

```
SELECT parameter, value
FROM
    (
        SELECT
           parameter,
            value
        FROM
            table r1
        WHERE
            r1.parameter IN (
                'Room meal',
                'Snacks between meals',
                'Reduction',
                'Mornings',
                'Noons',
                'Evenings',
                'Remarks'
            )
            AND r1.id= 1122632
                AND r1.wert IS NOT NULL
            AND r1.date= (
                SELECT
                    MAX(date)
                FROM
                    table r2
                WHERE
                    r2.parameter = r1.parameter
                    AND r2.id= r1.id
            ) 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            parameter,
            wert
        FROM
            table r1
        WHERE
            r1.parameter = 'Status'
                AND r1.id= 1122632
                AND r1.wert IS NOT NULL
    ) l
ORDER BY decode(l.parameter, 'Room meal', 1, 'Snacks between meals', 2, 'Reduction', 3, 'Mornings',4, 'Noons',5, 'Evenings',6, 'Remarks',7, 'Status', 8) asc;
```

and i am expecting the result of select to be something like this:

```
Parameter               Value
_________|_____________|________
Room meal              |Yes
Snacks between meals   |Yes
Reduction              |1500 kcal
Mornings               |Cookies
Noons                  |Cereals
Evenings               |Soup
Status                 |Adapted whole food
Status                 |Vegetarian food
```

but instead of this it comes in this format:

```
Parameter               Value
_________|_____________|________
Room meal              |Yes
Snacks between meals   |Yes
Reduction              |1500 kcal
Noons                  |Cereals
Evenings               |Soup
Mornings               |Cookies
Status                 |Adapted whole food
Status                 |Vegetarian food
```

Could you help me to resolve it?

Comment: The code you've shown won't behave like that so you've probably changed something important while editing/rewriting for posting (when also changing table/column names to illegal values). Unless `parameter` is defined as `char` rather than `varchar2`... that would make the decode redundant. Please provide a [mcve], with table creation statement so we can see the column data types, and inserts with representative data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: We cannot know the reason without source data as `insert` statements. Maybe some symbols are different, maybe there are spaces somwhere in the code. Which debug steps have you already performed? If you try to create **minimal reproducible** example you most likely to resolve the problem by yourself while doing it minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result of your decode:

```
SELECT parameter,
       value,
       decode(l.parameter, 'Room meal', 1, 'Snacks between meals', 2, 'Reduction', 3, 'Mornings',4, 'Noons',5, 'Evenings',6, 'Remarks',7, 'Status', 8)
FROM ...
```

So you can see the result of the decode expression and perhaps the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see you would get that result is if the `parameter` column is defined as `char` instead of `varchar2`; then [this aspect of `decode()` behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DECODE.html) would be relevant:

> If *expr* and *search* are character data, then Oracle compares them using nonpadded comparison semantics.

If your column is `char` then you end up comparing, for example, `'Status                        '` including padding up to the declared length of the column, with `'Status'` with no extra padding. Those string are not the same, so none of them match, and the result of the decode is always null (as you haven't supplied a final default argument).

That means the `order by decode() asc` is essentially always ordering by null, which doesn't do anything; so there is effectively no ordering at all, and you will get the results back in whatever indeterminate order they are retrieved from the underlying data by the optimiser.

You can get around that by using a case expression instead:

```
...
ORDER BY
    case l.parameter
        when 'Room meal' then 1
        when 'Snacks between meals' then 2
        when 'Reduction' then 3
        when 'Mornings' then 4
        when 'Noons' then 5
        when 'Evenings' then 6
        when 'Remarks' then 7
        when 'Status' then 8
    end asc;
```

You could also use a CTE to avoid having to list all of the parameter names twice, and set those values and priorities (i.e. ordering) at the same time, which can make the code shorter and easier to maintain - though it still needs different handling for Status. That's a bit off-topic but I've included examples in db<>fiddles showing what happens [if the column is `varchar2`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a02b38e7429deb47914dcd578ad2c7a3) and [if the column is `char`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=730cd7ae7390c7b2a602869667df4bc8).

You could possibly simplify even further by using a collection; but I'm wary of relying on the element order being honoured - I've never seen it *not* be, but that doesn't mean it's guaranteed.